# Localhost launch fails due to pending migration error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Issue: I am unable to launch localhost of the website we are developing in my local system. So I could play with it and write automated tests. Earlier it used to work.

The commands I run usually after Fetching Origin - of the Develop branch through Github app

1. bundle install
2. rake db:migrate
3. rails s

Now, the rake db:migrate is not working, giving me an error

> Macs-iMac:mac$ bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
>
> == 20180619223217 CreateCarts: migrating ======================================
>
> -- create_table(:carts)
>
> rails aborted!
>
> StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'carts' already exists: CREATE TABLE `carts`
>   (`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `user_id` int,
>   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL)
>   ENGINE=InnoDB
>
> /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in
>   `_query'
>
> /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in
>   `block in query'
>
> /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in
>   `handle_interrupt'
>
> /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in
>   `query'
>
> .. many lines like this..

There are many tables at least 8 of them like "carts" already exists it says.

Following troubleshooting have been done.

1. I tried to do rake db:reset / rails db:reset - It gave me error like "You are attempting to run a destructive action"
2. imported new data for the dev table on Sequelpro, then ran rake db:migrate
3. None of these three commands also worked, same "destructive action" error. rails db:drop, rails db:schema:load, rails db:reset

I went into db/migrate folder, and in-commented the lines that create those 8 issue tables. 
This seems to work, able to launch the app, but obviously some menus in the app don't work.

Switching through older versions of the app I had in the system in different feature branches I created months back, is working.

How do I solve this? and get on to launch the app :)

Comment: What's the exact error you get when you try `rails db:drop`? Have you tried googling that error message to see how others have gotten past it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rails db:reset DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1`in (1)

Comment: It drops and creates all the tables except for those 8 tables/ it lists out those 8 pending migrations in the end.

Comment: you can check if there is any migration that created "carts" table before, and now you may create it again, that will cause this migration error

Comment: There were no previous instances of 'carts' table creation. I found only two 'create table' in the migrate folder causing this trouble. Migration passed for now after a doing couple of times of commenting and uncommenting the lines in between def..end of create tables. The problem tables should have been skipped some how.